# Which expression is larger?

Tags: no-computers, number-theory

Without using a calculator/computer, please show steps to determine which expression is larger:

$(2^{90})!\quad vs.\quad2^{30!}$

Comment: "please show steps to determine"… Well, here are the steps: multiply them out by hand. (You didn't say we ourselves have to determine which is larger. Just that we should show the steps.)

Comment: @msh210 Technically I think that is only describing the steps, not showing them... And since the resulting numbers have like 10^30 digits I think you will hit the post character limit trying to write them out =)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> $2^{90}! < (2^{90})^{2^{90}} < 2^{2^{97}} < 2^{30!}$
>  The first inequality is obvious, the second comes from $90<2^7$, and the last one requires a wee bit of justification.
>  Expand the product $30!$, and replace every number with the greatest power of two not greater than it. You should obtain a product of two 2's, four 4's, eight 8's, and fifteen 16's - this comes out to ninety-four factors of two.
>  Now consider the product $3×5×6×7$. This comes out to $630$, which exceeds $2^9$, but in the reduced product these numbers became $2×4×4×4=2^7$. Therefore our reduction removed two powers of two, and two more from the product $12×20×24×28$, which is more than enough to yield $2^{97}<30!$.

EDIT: Even simpler and stronger argument:

> Instead of rounding down to the last power of two, we round as follows:
>  For each power of two $2^k$, we round down every number in $[2^k,3×2^{k-1})$ to $2^k$, and round down every number in $[3×2^{k-1},2^{k+1})$ to $2^k\sqrt2$.
>  Now we have $30! > 2^1×(2\sqrt2)^1×4^2×(4\sqrt2)^2×8^4×(8\sqrt2)^4×16^8×(16\sqrt2)^7 = 2^{101}$

Comment: @  AxiomaticSystem -- I did not know about your method.

Comment: +1 Nice argument, concisely explained!

Comment: Pretty sure a computer of some kind was used to post this :p

Comment: @JonathanAllan That does not violate the no-computers tag.

Comment: @mathlander yeah it was tongue in cheek regarding the question's wording, not a serious comment about this answer (which I upvoted)!

Answer (score 9):

The larger expression is

> $2^{30!}$.

Proof:

> Using [Stirling's bound for all positive n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $$\sqrt{2 \pi n}\ \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac{1}{12n + 1}} < n! < \sqrt{2 \pi n}\ \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac{1}{12n}},$$ we have $\log_2 30! > (\frac{30}{e})^{30}$, so  $$\log_2 \log_2 2^{30!} > 30\log_2 \frac{30}{e}.$$ On the other hand, we have $\log_2 (2^{90})! < 2^{90}(90-\log_2 e + \epsilon)$, where $\epsilon < 1$, so $$\log_2\log_2 (2^{90})!<90+\log_2 90 < 97 < 100.$$ But we have $11e < 11\times 2.72 < 30$, so it remains to show that  $$\log_2 11 > \frac{100}{30}=\frac{10}{3},$$ which is true because $11^3 = 1331 > 1024 = 2^{10}$.

Remark:

> Thanks for the puzzle! Perhaps there is a more elegant solution available. A computer shows a stronger result $2^{30!}>(2^{100})!$ but would be harder to prove by hand.

Comment: Could you see yourself doing this puzzle if you did not know Stirling's bound for all positive n?